# Laravel: AppServiceProvider to register an API Key?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm pretty new to Larvel, so apologies in advance for what I assume is a trivial question.

I'm building a store page using Stripe as my payment processor, and their PHP library requires users to register an API key.

Up to this point, I have been setting my API key in the first line of my Controller that creates the checkout session. This seems unnatural to me, and I thought that there would be a better way to "globally" set this API key upon the application boot up.

I then came across the AppServiceProvider, which I understand can be used to perform tasks on startup. I am now setting my API key in it's register() function, like so:

```
public function register() {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
}
```

**This works but I am wondering if this is normal and best-practice**. The Laravel documentation mentions that this is a good place for registering event listeners or even routes, but doesn't mention anything similar to API keys or setting up the registration for third-party libraries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion is dont call env anywhere in your code other than config file.Better create config file in config folder.

For example create a file called `stripe.php` in `config` folder

```
<?php

return [
    'stripe_secret_key'=>env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
];
```

Then you can access

```
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('stripe.stripe_secret_key'));
```

This helps when you cache config.If you run php artisan config:cache then it wont call env

As per documentation

> If you execute the config:cache command during your deployment
> process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function
> from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been
> cached, the .env file will not be loaded and all calls to the env
> function will return null.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-env

difference between register and boot method

> “After all providers have been registered, they are “booted”. This
> will fire the boot method on each provider. A common mistake when
> using service providers is attempting to use the services provided by
> another provider in the register method. Since, within the register
> method, we have no gurantee all other providers have been loaded, the
> service you are trying to use may not be available yet. So, service
> provider code that uses other services should always live in the boot
> method. The register method should only be used for, you guessed it,
> registering services with the container. Within the boot method, you
> may do whatever you like: register event listeners, include a routes
> file, register filters, or anything else you can imagine.”
>
> So the register one is just for binding. The boot one is to actually
> trigger something to happen.

Ref: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/difference-between-boot-and-register-method

Comment: "This works but I am wondering if this is normal and best-practice." is clearly looking for an opinion, which is off-topic. You should not be answering these questions.

Comment: @miken32.i agree with you .i just wanted to mention so if any one looking for similar answer then can refer

Comment: If anyone is looking for a similar answer, their question is also off-topic and should be closed.

Comment: @miken32.okay. got it :)

Comment: @miken32 where should we go when we are looking for an opinion?

Comment: @ElieMorin a forum like [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/) would be my first choice. Questions that solicit opinions are off-topic because there is no "right" answer. Best practices change, and everyone has different ways to do things.